# How do I convert this list sort function from Python 2 to Python 3

Tags: python

When I try to port it it errors out asking for key2

Python 2:

```
def SortItems(self,sorter=cmp):
    items = list(self.itemDataMap.keys())
    items.sort(sorter)
    self.itemIndexMap = items
    self.Refresh()
```

Python 3:

```
try:
    cmp
except NameError:
    def cmp(x, y):
        if x < y:
            return -1
        elif x > y:
           return 1
        else:
            return 0

def SortItems(self,sorter=cmp):
    items = list(self.itemDataMap.keys())
    items.sort(key=sorter)
    self.itemIndexMap = items
    self.Refresh()
```

Getting the error:

```
items.sort(key=sorter)
TypeError: __ColumnSorter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key2'
```

It looks like lambda function needs second argument
Any idea how to make it work?

Also tried functools.cmp_to_key:

```
def SortItems(self):
    import locale
    items = list(self.itemDataMap.keys())
    items= sorted(items, key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll)) 
    self.itemIndexMap = items   
    self.Refresh()
```

Getting error:

```
    items= sorted(items, key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll))
TypeError: strcoll() argument 1 must be str, not int
```

Probably because I'm sorting integers not strings

How do I make it work for int?

Answer (score 1):

`cmp` and `key` are fundamentally different. However there is a conversion function you can use: [`functools.cmp_to_key()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key).

Comment: Tried it, gives different error. TypeError: strcoll() argument 1 must be str, not int. I'm sorting integers. Any idea how to use it for integers?

Comment: What? Why are you using the `strcoll` function to compare integers? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs Python3 list.sort():

> sort() accepts two arguments that can only be passed by keyword
>   (keyword-only arguments)
>
> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element (for example, key=str.lower).

That is, the key callable only takes a single argument in py3. So in this case doing

`items.sort(int)`, or equivalently `items.sort(lambda x: x)`

will sort a list of int in ascending order.

In general `cmp` should return the comparison property of the each element
of the `list`.

```
def cmp(x):
   # code to compute comparison property or value of x
   # eg. return x % 5
```

Additionally, you *can* convert the python2 cmp function:

> The functools.cmp_to_key() utility is available to convert a 2.x style
>   cmp function to a key function.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort